# How to Add Ctrl+P as shortcut to print in VB 6.0 projects

Tags: vb6

I'm having various controls and methods that deploy to my ERP Project like "ERP_VAL_TrnOvrProfit_FinYear" where I'm going to do some huge operation for a report and also have the "Command button for print" only i want to add a shortcut to key to that command button.

1). I want to add "Ctr+P" combination as shortcut to print dialogue in my new VB 6.0 project, can I have a sample code for that.

2). And where can I write the shortcut key combination either in form level load or some where else?

Comment: If you have a menu on the form the shortcut is a property of the menu item, and Ctrl+P is an appropriate shortcut. If you're adding it to a command button, add an ampersand before the P,  (&Print), and you will have a Shift + P shortcut which is appropriate for a button.

Comment: Good comment @jac except that if you add an ampersand to the caption of a command button, the shortcut is `Alt + P` not `Shift + P`

Answer (score 0):

I hope am not too late to answer this question. Right click on an empty place inside the form and you will see the menu editor as the second item on the context menu. It the wizard that has all that you need. The auto generated code may look like this:

```
Begin VB.Menu mnuMenu 
      Caption         =   "&File"
      Begin VB.Menu mnuArrowDown 
         Caption         =   "&Print"
         Shortcut        =   ^P
      End
      Begin VB.Menu mnuExit 
         Caption         =   "E&xit"
         Shortcut        =   ^Q
      End
   End
```